# ¿Por qué no me cargan las imágenes de mi ruta en github cuando utilizo github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un pequeño proyecto de *PokeDex* en *github* y quiero consumir las imágenes que tengo en una ruta en el mismo proyecto, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo en *github pages* no me aparecen las imágenes, pero en local si me las encuentra... entonces quiero saber porque pasa ese tipo de errores, adjunto algunas capturas.

Github:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ruta de imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código que busca las imágenes:

```
pokemon.types.forEach(element => {

    if(element.type.name == 'electric'){
        const imgType = document.createElement('img');
        imgType.setAttribute("class", "types");
        imgType.src = '../resources/img_types/electric_type.png';
        pdivstats.appendChild(imgType);
    }
```

Alguno puede explicarme ¿Por qué no me trae las imágenes en mi ruta de *github*?.

Comment: Puedes probar cambiando la ruta a `'./resources/img_types/electric_type.png';` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque el script js este dentro de una subcarpeta `js` por ejemplo, la ruta esta relativa a la pagina html que carga dicho script, no el script en si, por lo que la ruta de imagen seria (suponiendo que el HTML que lo carga es el index.html)

```
imgType.src = './resources/img_types/electric_type.png';
```

Notar que en CSS la ruta relativa de imagenes si depende de la ubicacion del archivo, por lo que cualquier archivo dentro de `css` si debera usar la ruta relativa `../resources/...` para acceder a la carpeta en el mismo nivel